# How to get resourcesServerFilter defined in ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-java-config

I'm in the process of transfering xml to Java configuration for oauth2 resource server.

By extending *ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter* and using *@EnableResourceServer*, a resourcesServerFilter (*OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter*) is automatically added to Spring Security filter chain (at the position before *AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter*).

I want to add that filter into my filter chain, and then place that filter chain to Spring Security filter chain before *AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter*. I don't see the way to get the instance of *OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter* defined in *ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer*.

I tried to create an instance of *OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter* and it worked well, but that way there are two instances of *OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter* (the one that I created and the one that's automatically created) and the request goes through the same *doFilter* method twice. I also tried to remove *@EnableResourceServer* annotation (to skip automatic creation of the *OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter*), but then I lost lots of other defaults.

What is the right way to do this?

In xml config, there is something like

```
<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" ... />
```

and I could fetch resource server filter by its id and place it in my filter chain.